# Definite integral of $\sqrt{\log\left(1+\frac{1}{2x}\right)}$

Tags: definite-integrals

Can someone explain to me how to solve the integral
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 \sqrt{\log\left(\frac{1}{2x}+1\right)}\mathrm{d} x
\end{align*}

I know it is finite by simulation in R

```
fun <- function(x) sqrt(log(1+1/(2*x)))
integrate(fun, 0, 1)
0.9304908 with absolute error < 5.4e-07
```

by I also would like to solve it with pen and paper :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: First thing I tried: integral is equal to $\int_0^1 \sqrt{\log(2x+1) - \log(2x)}$

Comment: Also, where does this integral appear in your studies?

Comment: Yeah, I tried the same as you! I bumped into that integral when dealing with the log-entropy metric of sets.

Comment: Equivalent to $(1/2)\int_{3/2}^{\infty}\sqrt{\ln u}/(u-1)^2 du$. $\sqrt{\ln u}/(u-1)^2$ doesn't look likely to have a closed-form antiderivative.

Comment: Mmmm, I see. Let me slightly change the question then. How can I prove that it is finite?

Comment: It is finite. You know that $\log (1+a)<a$ for $a>0$. Therefore, $\log (1+1/2x)<1/2x$. Since $\int_0^1 x^{-1/2}dx$ is convergent, your integral is convergent by comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that we could find a closed form result but we can use nice bounds using for example the Padé approximants of the upper and lower bounds of $\log(1+x)$ (have a look at Table $1$ [here](https://rgmia.org/papers/v7n2/pade.pdf)).

Using the second one, after changing $x$ to $\frac 1{2x}$, we have
$$\sqrt{\frac{3(4 x+1)}{24x^2+12 x +1}}<\sqrt{\log \left(1+\frac{1}{2 x}\right)}<\sqrt{\frac{12 x+1}{8 x (3 x+1)}}$$ Both lhs and rhs lead to explicit antiderivatives (not very simple) and then definite integrals.
Integrated between $0$ and $1$,the decimal representations of the results are $0.91495$ and $1.02867$ while the solution is $0.93049$  as you found.